# Frequent use of the pronoun "We" in "I" stead

Tags: multilingualism

Does any language have a word for the situation when somebody frequently uses the pronoun "We" in "I" stead in his speach?

By analogy with the german pronoun du(thou) -> duzen (use the informal form of address/call someone by their first name) or with the russian pronoun "ты"(thou) -> тыкать (use the informal form...)

Comment: Not exactly the name for such situation, but a similar thing: In Korean, the first person plural possessive "우리 /u.ri/" replaces the first person singular possessive "나의 or 내 /na.e/ or /nɛ/" in informal speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English this is commonly called the *royal we*, or *nosism* more formally.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism